# merge or join unequal data and duplicate value of one of them in sas

Tags: database, dataframe, join, merge, sas

I am trying to merge 2 datasets (`df1`, `df2`) with the one of them `df2` has only 1 observation that I want to assign its value to all length of the `df1` duplicate with merge in `sas`.
I am aware that I can add that manually but I want to use automated way as this is just a step in my long code with big data.

Here is a reproducible example and datasets:

```
data df1;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 2 3
6 7 8
5 6 9 
;
run;

data df2;
input d ;
datalines;
4  
;
run;

data df3;
merge df1 df2;
run;

/*I need the resulting df3 to be */;

a b c d
1 2 3 4
6 7 8 4
5 6 9 4
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you don't want to MERGE the dataset, since there are no common variables that the merge could actually use.

Instead just SET both datasets, but take care to not read past the end of single observation set.

```
data want;
  set long_dataset;
  if _n_=1 then set short_dataset;
run;
```

Comment: Thx a lot. That works. Appreciate it. Upvoted!